# Not containing defenition or extension method accepting argument of type

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I am doing a data types exercise and when I try to create a method for a data types class, I get an error:

> Error    1    'Data_Type_Explanations' does not contain a definition for 'RunExercize' and no extension method 'RunExercize' accepting a first argument of type 'Data_Type_Explanations' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)     \data-types\data-types\Program.cs 39    17    PCE_01

This is the code I partly implemented:

*In main:*

```
Data_Type_Explanations dte = new Data_Type_Explanations();
            dte.RunExercize();
```

*outside:*

```
class Data_Type_Explanations
{
    public void RunExercise()
    {

        sbyte x = 3; // stores from -128 to +127
        Console.WriteLine("Value of x is: " + x);
    }
}
```

I don't understand the error message. Why is it telling that the method is not in the class, while it is there?

Comment: Please look at your code and read carefully the method name in the compiler error message.

Comment: Typos are sometimes impossible to see, however many times you read the code! Take dymanoids hint and look carefully....

Comment: thank you dymanoid, Tompsett.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your method name. Try the following code in main:

```
Data_Type_Explanations dte = new Data_Type_Explanations();
dte.RunExercise();
```

Comment: ** resolved as per kmatyaszek's answer

**syntax mispelling

Exercise vs. Exercize.

Thanks, K